# Делаю апишку, но видает ошибку возле знака "="

Tags: mysql, .net, api, webapi

Вот сам код:

```
[HttpPut]
            public JsonResult Put(Employee emp)
            {
                string query = @"
                        update dbo.Employee set 
                        EmployeeName = '" + emp.EmployeeName + @"'
                        ,Department = '" + emp.Department + @"'
                        ,DateOfJoining = '" + emp.DateOfJoining + @"'
                        where EmployeeId = " + emp.EmployeeId + @"
                        ";
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeAppCon");
                SqlDataReader myReader;
                using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
                {
                    myCon.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                    {
                        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        table.Load(myReader); ;
                        myReader.Close();
                        myCon.Close();
                    }
                }
                return new JsonResult("Added successfully");
            }

[HttpPut]
        public JsonResult Put(Employee emp)
        {
            string query = @"
                    update dbo.Employee set 
                    EmployeeName = '" + emp.EmployeeName + @"'
                    ,Department = '" + emp.Department + @"'
                    ,DateOfJoining = '" + emp.DateOfJoining + @"'
                    where EmployeeId = " + emp.EmployeeId + @"
                    ";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeAppCon");
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                {
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    table.Load(myReader); ;
                    myReader.Close();
                    myCon.Close();
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult("Added successfully");
        }
```

[image: Put]

Answer (score 0):

```
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Метод `ExecuteReader` предназначен для выполнения операции `SELECT`.

[ExecuteNonQuery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

---

```
                /*myReader = */myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //table.Load(myReader); ;
                //myReader.Close();
                //myCon.Close();
```

Comment: Все равно видает ошибку "The numbers of rows affected". CS0029

Comment: @sanchosmore Я не знаю, как выглядит Ваш код, который `Все равно видает ошибку "The numbers of rows affected". CS0029`

Comment: Я обновил код, ниже это новий код

Comment: @sanchosmore Я дал Вам ссылку на документацию. Там есть пример кода. Вы документацию не прочитали. Вы из детского сада сюда пришли?

Comment: У меня два файла, в одном функция с зазначеними компонентами работает, в другом нет, думал может ошибка типа не латиницей написал или того же типа!?

Comment: @sanchosmore `'literal'` и `N'literal'` - немножко не одно и то же.

Comment: То что ви хотите посоветовать?(мог не понять, еще без опита в этой сфере)